# Is it possible to access anonymous outer classes?

Tags: scala, class, inner-classes

The easy way is to specify `this` declaration in outer class bodies to define unique name for each class. But I'd like to write access without modifying outer classes.

Code example:

```
trait Test {
  def z = new Test {
    val a = 1
    def y = new Test {
      val a = false
      def x = new Test {
        val b = 2 * a
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to access `outer.outer.a` instead of just outer.a when defining `val b`

How can I specify `this` of an anonymous class? If it was `Named`, I could write `Named.this`, but anonymous classes has no names.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with [self types](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/self-types.html):

```
trait Test { greatGrandparent =>
  def z = new Test { grandparent =>
    val a = 1
    def y = new Test { parent =>
      val a = false
      def x = new Test {
        val b = 2 * grandparent.a
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I could not modify parent classes, they are given. I could not read self reference from symbol, because it is already erased. Hence the question: how to refer parent class without relying on self-type feature, as I mentioned in the very first question abstract

Comment: The reference for `greatGrandparent` is the only place where the parent class is adjusted. I suppose I don't understand the question well enough--
 for `grandParent` and `parent`, self types should be fine.

Comment: you could not modify outer classes, could not add self types to them. They could already has self references shaded by a variable in a method. I need a robust way to refer greatgrandparent without making any additional assumptions like self reference availability